# why is my query returning the right max value but not the corresponding name that goes with that average value?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is averaging the ratings of a restaurant (from a separate review table) and I'm trying to get the max value out of that. Here is what a query getting the average rating based on joining a restaurant to its reviews gets:

```
1   Panera  4.0000
2   BurgerKing  4.5000
3   ChuckECheese    2.6667
4   Cafe Gratitude  2.0000
```

However, I'm trying to get just the restaurant with the highest review and its rating and I'm using this query:

```
select BusinessName, MAX(AvgReview) as Rating from
(select BusinessName, avg(ReviewRating) as AvgReview
from Business
join Review 
on Review.BusinessID = Business.BusinessID 
group by Business.BusinessID) AvgRatingsTable;
```

But that is resulting in:

```
Panera  4.5000
```

Where it gets the maximum rating correctly but not the restaurant name. I've tried doing adding "where AvgRating = Max(AvgRating)" but it says invalid use of group function.

Additionally, when I try to find the restaurant with the minimum review using:

```
select AvgRatingsTable.BusinessName, MIN(AvgRatingsTable.AvgReview) as Rating from
(select BusinessName, avg(ReviewRating) as AvgReview
from Business
join Review 
on Review.BusinessID = Business.BusinessID 
group by Business.BusinessName) AvgRatingsTable;
```

I receive

```
BurgerKing  2.0000
```

So doing groupby BusinessName or BusinessID doesn't really help; it just grabs the first name.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I tell it I want the name that corresponds to that maximum/minimum average?

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

If I do this, with a groupby on the outer query

```
select AvgRatingsTable.BusinessName, MIN(AvgRatingsTable.AvgReview) as Rating from
(select BusinessName, avg(ReviewRating) as AvgReview
from Business
join Review 
on Review.BusinessID = Business.BusinessID 
group by Business.BusinessName) AvgRatingsTable
group by BusinessName;
```

It just returns all of the tables instead of at least giving me the minimum rating. Same if I do groupby BusinessName, AvgReview.

Comment: I find it odd that MySQL is actually producing anything at all, other than an error message. You're essentially doing this: `select x, max(y) from z`, with no `GROUP BY`. Either MySQL is deferring the error message of using an aggregate function in conjunction with a non-aggregate expression until it actually finds more than one row in the result or there is something else going on here that you haven't told us about. By all means, MySQL *should* complain that `BusinessName` is not part of a `GROUP BY` clause and therefore not valid in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Can you verify that these are the **actual** SQL's you've tried?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Copy pasted directly from MySQL workbench.   Edit: I had tried doing a groupby on the oustide too before but it just made all the average ratings show up. (Added it to my original question too now)